# Winforms Graphics Disappear After Refreshing DataGridView DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, graphics

So I inherited this WinForms app which does a lot of graphics drawing.  A grid of sorts is drawn on the form by repeatedly calling the following method:

```
    private void DrawCell(int startx, int starty, int width, int height, System.Drawing.Color fill, string text = "")
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(fill))
            {
                Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(startx, starty, width, height);
                formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, temp);
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(formGraphics, temp, System.Drawing.Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

                if (text != "")
                {
                    Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(formGraphics, text, font2, temp, Color.Blue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The process to draw this "grid" is initiated by selecting an item in a ComboBox, which calls a "DrawGrid" method to loop through a known quantity of rows and columns and call the above method in the loops.

I added a DataGridView control to the form.  In addition to updating the above "grid", I now want to update the DataGridView.  So in the ComboBox's SelectedValueChanged event, I also call a method to get the data values (simple one-dimentional array of numbers) and update the DGV's DataSource with the array.

So here's the problem:  When I choose an item in the ComboBox, the "fake" grid draws and immediately disappears THE FIRST TIME ONLY, but thereafter everything works just fine.  The "fake" grid then draws properly and does not disappear.

This happens no matter in which order I draw the "fake" grid or update the DataGridView.  If I comment out the line setting the DGV's DataSource, the "fake" grid works fine, even the first time.

Any ideas why this might be happening?  I'm not using the form's OnPaint event at all.

Thanks...

Comment: _this.CreateGraphics()_ - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - Note it will disappear after minimzing the form. In your case you need to use the CellPainting event and its e.Grpahics object!

Comment: @Taw, thanks.  I'm not really a graphics person, and I inherited this application.  Is there any way to fix this?  It's just a bunch of cells, not from a bitmap.  The draw method may be called from different places at different times.  Is there a type of control I could use, then leverage it's on-paint event?  Thanks...

Comment: In a DataGridView you can and should use the CellPaintining event. Do have a good look at its many parameters, which will not only supply you with a valid Graphics object but also with data on the Cell and its content and cellbounds; also a few methods that take out the hard work of Painting the content, background etc..

Comment: So the DataGridView has nothing to do with the "fake" grid being drawn on the form.  I added it to another area of the form to track some properties.  It's not related to the "fake" grid at all, and I don't need to worry about it's graphics.  The basic drawing of the "fake" grid and updating it during program operation is the issue. So could I move all the code to the form's on-paint event, and use flags to control what to draw, then force repaint when needed?

Comment: Hm, no; anthing a control (or form) draw will sit __under__ any of its child controls. If you need a drawn grid on the DGV you can use the DGV's Paint event. But I have a hunch you don't actully want to draw on a DGV after all? The most direct fix may be this: Add a Graphics parameter to the DrawCell function and use it instead of the volatile one created there before. Then, in the Paint event trigger either the DrawCell, passing out the e.Graphics, or, more likely there is a loop or two, which supply the params; then pass it into those. Whichever it must be the one..

Comment: ..coming from the Paint event and it must happen triggered from the Paint event. If you have some other event that is triggering the drawing now, replace it by calling Invalidate, which in turn will trigger the Paint event. - All this may seem a little weird, but it it done this way, because the system itself will also trigger the Paint event it it must get a chance to do the exact same things! - Btw: do not put the Graphics object into a `suing` clause, as it was not created by you, just passed on. Also do not try to cache it as it will not stay valid..

Comment: I think I understand all of what you said, except I'm confused as to why you keep referring to the DGV's Paint event and the DrawCell function.  The graphics being drawn on the form have nothing to do with the DGV at all.  They are on the form itself, and are physically apart from the DGV, so z-order of graphics and DGV are unimportant.  I think maybe setup some data structure which controls how many rows and columns to draw and their sizes, then use that in the form's Paint event, & use its e.graphics object?

Comment: Um, no, now I mean the Paint/OnPaint event of the Form!

Comment: Ok, I was totally confused here (my fault).  Now I see. In the form's Paint event, call the other methods that were being called directly, but pass them the e.Graphics object.  Make that paint event happen by using Invalidate instead of calling those other methods directly.  I only need to set some flags first so the Paint event knows which of the other driver methods to call (either initial one, to draw default "grid" or update one to draw new updated "grid"). Does that seem right?

Comment: Sounds spot on!

Comment: Thanks so much.  If you want to put something from these comments into an actual answer, I will certainly give you credit.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I shold re-open the question. All I wrote are basic rules of Winforms graphics and I and others have written about them rather often.. If you run into problems feel free to ping me or to write a new question..